# verb tense in reported speech

Tags: verbs, tenses, backshifting, indirect-speech

> 1. I told Cindy we would not be able to eat American Chinese food again for a couple of years, once we **moved** to Shanghai.
> 2. I told Cindy we would not be able to eat American Chinese food again for a couple of years, once we **move** to Shanghai.

CONTEXT: We have not moved yet. It will happen in the future. But I am recording a conversation that happened in the past--a few hours ago.

My question is: Should I write "once we ***moved*** to Shanghai" or "once we ***move*** to Shanghai"?

That is, should I use "moved" (#1) in order to be consistent with the tense in the rest of the sentence?

---

**Update (16 hours later):** When I wrote my question last night I didn't realise that the tense of "will" should be, and in this case can be consistent with the tense of "move". It is true the impossibility of eating American Chinese food (I crave General Tso's chicken) will occur in the future. I feel now more comfortable saying "I told Cindy that we will not..., once we move...".

Comment: It could actually go either way, depending on what you want to convey. If the move is still in your future, you could use *move*. If in the past, *moved*.

Comment: One more victim of "sequence-of-tenses" zombie rules. There are no such rules in English, regardless of what your English teacher said. You never thought your English teacher spoke English all that well, anyway, did you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, judging from the way it works for me, anyway, "move" in the example is not grammatical.  If it were a direct quote, it would approximate:

> I told Cindy: "We will not be able to eat American Chinese food again for a couple of
>   years, once we move to Shanghai."

When it is converted to indirect discourse, the verbs shift tense to agree with the past tense "told", "will" becomes "would" and "move" becomes "moved".  It might be possible to leave tenses unshifted, to get:

> I told Cindy we will not be able to eat American Chinese food again for a couple of years, once we move to Shanghai.

but since the "will" has been shifted to "would", I think you have to shift the "move" to "moved", as well.

Comment: And what if you hadn't yet made the move but still intended to? How would you differentiate that without using *move*? In fact, either is entirely grammatical.

Comment: @Robusto, if you haven't made the move yet, you can use the unshifted version with "move", as I said in my answer, but then you have to use "will" instead of "would", because the inability to eat American Chinese food is also in the future.  The question is about whether you can use "move" leaving the "would" unchanged, and you can't.  My answer is correct.

Comment: Nope, sorry, it's not.

Comment: I agree with Robusto here—shifting _would_ but leaving _move_ is perfectly fine for me, too (as is leaving both unshifted). Shifting _moved_ somehow jars to me since we know that the move is a future event: it implies the move has already happened. The only option that definitely does **not** work for me is shifting _moved_ and not shifting _will_: I can think of no possible way to make “I told her we won’t be able to do that once we went to Shanghai” grammatical.

Comment: I guess I have a looser idiolect than you do, @Greg. They both seem fine to me.